# Methods in trait are not getting specialized

Tags: scala, generics, specialized-annotation

Let the following setup:

```scala
sealed trait Test[@specialized T] {

  implicit protected def tag: ClassTag[T]

  def xs: Array[T]

  def count(condition: T => Boolean): Int = {
    @tailrec
    def innerLoop(index: Int, acc: Int): Int =
      if (index == xs.length) acc
      else {
        val c: Int = if (condition(xs(index))) 1 else 0
        innerLoop(index + 1, acc + c)
      }

    innerLoop(0, 0)
  }

  def freq(elem: T): Int = count(_ == elem)

}

object Test {

  def apply[@specialized T: ClassTag](xs: Array[T]): Test[T] = if(xs.length % 2 == 0) TestA(xs) else TestB(xs)

  final case class TestA[@specialized T: ClassTag](xs: Array[T]) extends Test[T] {
    protected def tag: ClassTag[T] = classTag[T]
  }

  final case class TestB[@specialized T: ClassTag](xs: Array[T]) extends Test[T] {
    protected def tag: ClassTag[T] = classTag[T]
  }
}
```

In this case, both `count` and `freq` methods can be computed in a generic way, though other methods might exist that are specific to `TestA` or `TestB`.

When I benchmark the `count` method, then there's no performance increase and my feeling is, that somewhere `specialized` annotation is lost. The same happens with `freq` too. When the `count` method is defined in the case classes, then it works as expected and boxing-unboxing is avoided. But this approach will introduce a lot of code duplication.

Even when `count` is abstract and `freq` is defined in the trait

```scala
sealed trait Test[@specialized T] {

  implicit protected def tag: ClassTag[T]

  def xs: Array[T]

  def count(condition: T => Boolean): Int

  def freq(elem: T): Int = count(_ == elem)

}
```

and `count` is overridden in the case classes, the `freq` method won't be specialized either.
What am I missing? Is there a way to define some methods already in the trait and get them specialized?